# Does recording audio in the background on Android drain a devices battery?

Tags: android, power-management

If I have a service analyze audio in the background, will the battery die quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. There will be a noticable difference in power consumption, but not as much as for example the WiFi radio uses.

Answer (score 0):

Quickly = BatteryCapacity / WattNeededForBackgroundOperation